# Rome HttpClientFeedFetcher gives "Invalid XML" exception

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, rome

I am trying to use Rome and just for testing, I am attempting to fetch a simple RSS feed and keep getting "Invalid XML" error.  I implement the solution given in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104839/java-rome-i-am-trying-to-parse-rss-feed-but-get-a-error-on-some-channels) yet it's not working for me.  What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
  private void fetchRSSDetails()  {
    HttpClientFeedFetcher feedFetcher = new HttpClientFeedFetcher();
    try {
      SyndFeed feed = feedFetcher.retrieveFeed(new URL("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml"));
      System.out.println(feed.getLink());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException | FeedException | FetcherException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
 com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML
     at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:241)
     at com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput.build(SyndFeedInput.java:154)
     at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpClientFeedFetcher.retrieveFeed(HttpClientFeedFetcher.java:354)
     at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpClientFeedFetcher.getFeed(HttpClientFeedFetcher.java:261)
     at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpClientFeedFetcher.retrieveFeed(HttpClientFeedFetcher.java:246)
     at com.rometools.fetcher.impl.HttpClientFeedFetcher.retrieveFeed(HttpClientFeedFetcher.java:157)
     at com.my.feed.subscriptions.SearchTask.fetchRSSDetails(SearchTask.java:168)
     at com.my.feed.subscriptions.SearchTask.doInBackground(SearchTask.java:93)
     at com.my.feed.subscriptions.SearchTask.doInBackground(SearchTask.java:54)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: org.jdom2.JDOMException: http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl feature not recognized for SAX driver org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader
     at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.internalSetFeature(SAXBuilder.java:1025)
     at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.configureParser(SAXBuilder.java:976)
     at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.buildEngine(SAXBuilder.java:856)
     at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.getEngine(SAXBuilder.java:904)
     at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:1196)
     at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:234)
    ... 15 more
```

And here is how I add Rome to my Android project.

```
compile ('com.rometools:rome:1.5.1'){
    exclude module: 'slf4j-api'
}
compile ('com.rometools:rome-fetcher:1.5.1'){
    exclude module: 'slf4j-api'
}
```

I must be missing something simple... If any one could point me to any good documentation for Rome that might help.  Additionally, I am not set on Rome and any other RSS parsing library for java could do, if you want to recommend something easier to use.  I only need to parse RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't replicate your issue, but you could try to add your own user agent string for feed fetcher (in case they are redirecting certain user agents):

```
SyndFeed feed = feedFetcher.retrieveFeed("your-rss-reader-user-agent", new URL( "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml"));
```

See [also this issue about deprecation of rome-fetcher](https://github.com/rometools/rome/issues/276). There is an example on how to fetch feeds using Apache HttpClient.